# Ninject + WebApi + Custom Membership Provider + Property Injection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-membership, ninject

I have a repository that i use to access user info IAccountCore and I have a custom membership provider that I've implemented as well.  I have property injection setup in the membership provider but it seems that they're never injected. I've followed all the examples on the net to no avail.

I have the ninject bootstrapper + web activator firing the kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider) in the post startup method but the properties are always null.  Here are some code snippets:

Bootstrapper in WebApi

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PostApplicationStartMethod(typeof(API.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "RegisterMembership")]
```

Method being called from above:

```
public static void RegisterMembership()
{
    //bootstrapper.Kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);
    bootstrapper.Kernel.Load(new MembershipNinjectModule());
}
```

Ninject Module (in a different assembly/project):

```
public class MembershipNinjectModule : NinjectModule
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Loads the module into the kernel.
    /// </summary>
    public override void Load()
    {
        var kernel = Kernel;
        kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider);
    }
}
```

Property in custom membership provider:

```
[Inject]
public IAccountCore AccountCore {get;set;}
```

Bindings in another ninject module:

```
public class NinjectConfigurator : NinjectModule 
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        var kernel = Kernel
        kernel.Bind<IAccountCore>().To<AccountCore>().InTransientScope();
    }
}
```

Code that loads above module in the Ninject boot strapper:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Load(new NinjectConfigurator());
}
```

Comment: wheres it getting to, can you breakpoint on your inject call?

Comment: also why not this, //bootstrapper.Kernel.Inject(Membership.Provider); (you have it commented)

Comment: It gets to the custom membership provider's constructor, which then attempts to call the IAccountCore property which is null so a NullReferenceException is thrown.  As for the commented line - I get the same behavior I just described. The IAccountCore property is always null no matter which method I try.

Comment: So you are calling the injected property in the constructor of the membership provider? That wont work because it wont be injected till later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add on the constructor of your custom membership provider this line :

```
public MyCustomMembershipProvider()
{
    NinjectWebCommon.Kernel.Inject(this);
}
```

On my project, I used an custom membership provider with Ninject, and I just have this line more than you.

Hope it helps

Comment: Interesting - but the only problem is that my custom membership provider is in a different project that NinjectWebCommon.cs so it doesn't know what that is.

Comment: I got the same issue than you. I had the custom membership provider in another project too, but I didn't found an other way to solve this. I hope you found a better way :)